# Can the delete operator be used instead of the Marshal.FreeHGlobal method to free memory from a wchar_t*?

Tags: c++-cli

I read the [official documentation for the `StringToHGlobalUni` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobaluni?view=net-5.0#remarks) and it says that the `FreeHGlobal` method should be use to free memory.

The memory allocated by `StringToHGlobalUni` method is on the native heap, so I don't see why the **`delete`** operator could not be used.

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find any explanation why I can't use the **delete** operator.

I'm new to this and some explanations would help me. Can the delete operator be used or not ?

#### Code

```
const wchar_t* filePath = (const wchar_t*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(inputFilePath)).ToPointer();
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)filePath));
```

Comment: If you created the object using **new**, you must destruct the object using **delete**.  More importantly, if you *did not* create the object using **new**, you *must not* destruct the object using **delete**.

Comment: A (Windows) program can have more than one heap ...

Comment: Note that `FreeHGlobal` should be in a `finally`

Comment: @Eljay I didn't created the object *inputFilePath* using **new**. The *FreeHGlobal* [frees memory previously allocated from the unmanaged memory of the process.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal?view=net-5.0). I understand that it refers to the memory allocated by the *StringToHGlobalUni* method. I don't know how the memory is allocated by this method, but I expect it to be on the native heap. So why couldn't the **delete** operator be used? The answers so far are not entirely clear to me.

Comment: @PaulSanders answer's seems to be a good one. This method can allocate memory on a certain heap and only *FreeHGlobal* knows how to free it. But the problem is that I don't know how the memory is allocated by the *StringToHGlobalUni* method ...

Comment: Why should you care?  Just do what the documentation tells you to do.

Comment: I'm just curious :) What's wrong with that?

Comment: *FreeHGlobal* ≠ **delete**, so the answer to the question is "No, you cannot use the delete operator instead of FreeHGlobal."

Comment: @Eljay, but can you please tell me the difference? Thank you!

Comment: The difference is that **new** and **delete** manage the memory in the C++ free store and also construct and destruct objects, while **AllocHGlobal** and **FreeHGlobal** manages the memory in the unmanaged memory of the process.  **delete** does not call **FreeHGlobal**.  I'm not sure I understand what you do not understand about this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use `Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni` in C++/CLI.

Use either

1. `PtrToStringChars` (accesses Unicode characters in-place, no allocation) or
2. `marshal_as<std::wstring>` (manages the allocation with a smart pointer class that will free it correctly and automatically)

---

Apart from the fact that `StringToHGlobalUni` requires you to free the memory manually, the name of that function is completely misleading.  It has absolutely no connection to `HGLOBAL` whatsoever.